# Database design for a sell/rent eCommerce

Tags: mysql, database, e-commerce

I am working on my school project to create an eCommerce website that sell and rent product.

My main problem is that I can't find the best design for the "Renting" part. For now I am thinking about two designs:

The first database design suggestion:
[image: The first database design suggestion]

---

The second database design suggestion:
[image: The second database design suggestion]

As you can see there are the same tables in both designs but with different relations, but I can't tell which one is better.

I will be happy if you can tell me which design is better or if there is a better way to design my database altogether.

Comment: I'd suggest to add `-id_order` to the `rent_detail` and remove `id_product` and `id_customer`. They could be get from order.

Comment: ty, but which design is that ? bcz order doesn't have id_product

Comment: what editor u draw? there should be solid lines not dotted. From the order u can get items from items - product. both designs differ on only by `rent_detail`.

Comment: ty ,i used MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE too create the model from mysql script. you mean smth like this ? http://postimage.org/image/sq99bjk27/

Comment: are u talking about the dotted lines ? Identifying and Non-Identifying relations ?

Comment: I had thought about UML notation. Sorry, this is out of tag. Last one has correct relationship. Take a look on types, name PK as id INT or BIGINT. Foreign keys as xxx_id the same type.

Comment: thanks , so it better too split rents and sells apart. btw does naming PK change something ?

Comment: Proper naming is a key of successful development and maintenance. May be I'm wrong but I couldn't change the model without renaming attributes.

Comment: i don't think the last one is correct, if a customer rent 3 products and buy 2, the RENT table doesn't have the proper information to change the amount of products in PRODUCT table  when the customer send back one product. I should have posted the hole database :'(. thanks for the answers , i will use first model because i don't have enough time left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of your problem from the real-life perspective:

1. You will be offering “something”, being `products` in your schema;
2. You will be working with “somebody” or `customers` in your schema.

These 2 tables are most important, as without them the whole thing has no meaning.

Next, in real life, you have to have papers for each deal you'll make in order to:

1. Report to authorities and pay taxes (don't you like to pay taxes?);
2. Keep track of products that are “on hands” of your customers.

These are `orders` of 2 types: purchase and rent.

Note, though, that it is unlikelly to rent a set of products with different return dates in one order. Typically, one will rent a set of related items for some special case, like wedding celebration or bathroom repair. In case you need some products for 2 days while others for 2 weeks, it is better to create 2 orders, as different delivery conditions or discounts may apply.

Therefore I think that initial **variant #1** matches your goal better with the following updates:

1. `order_type` column should be added to the `orders` table;
2. `rent_details` should relate to `orders` table;
3. `rent_details` should have only `order_id` in place of `rent_detail_id` + `order_items_id`;
4. it very necessary to have a separate `price` column in the `order_items` table along with `discount`;

Comment: thanks for the answer, but sadly it a bit late i already finished my database, and started writing code for the website. here is a [link](http://postimage.org/image/guohxaa0l/),i think this this last design is better. what do u think ?

Comment: @user1559104, looks good. As long as it works for you, then it is fine.

Comment: how do you add a sale in the database table? for example, it's the ber months and the sale is only on a specific category shoes, clothes, and caps?